# Android app keep crashing to OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

My app keep crashing, and I can't understand what's wrong with it, been searching for answer everywhere, from what I understood, people said it is because of the device is out of memory, but I don't understand what is causing this ?

1. Is it because I have too many images in my res/drawable folder ?
2. Is it because I have one quite high resolution image in my res/drawable folder ?

If the problem is one of the above, what is the solution ? put the images in assets folder or what ? Below is the error stacks.
Thank you.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Class <? extends Activity> classVariable;
int last_level;
TextView text_play, text_level, game_title;
RelativeLayout playBtn, levelBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    playBtn = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
    levelBtn = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.levelBtn);
    game_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game_title);
    text_play = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_play);
    text_level = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_level);

    Typeface tf  = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/snap-itc.ttf");
    text_play.setTypeface(tf);
    text_level.setTypeface(tf);
    game_title.setTypeface(tf);

    // Check if file exists
    File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath("levels.json");
    if (file.exists()) {
        // Get the JSON Object from the data
        JSONObject parent = this.parseJSONData();

        try {
            last_level = parent.getInt("level");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    switch (last_level) {
        case 1:
            classVariable = Level002Activity.class;
            break;
        case 2:
            classVariable = Level003Activity.class;
            break;
        case 3:
            classVariable = Level004Activity.class;
            break;
        case 5:
            classVariable = Level005Activity.class;
            break;
        default:
            classVariable = Level001Activity.class;
    }

    playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Level002Activity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    levelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Level001Activity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

}

public JSONObject parseJSONData() {
    String JSONString = null;
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        // Open the inputStream to the file
        FileInputStream fin = openFileInput("levels.json");

        int sizeOfJSONFile = fin.available();

        // array that will store all the data
        byte[] bytes = new byte[sizeOfJSONFile];

        // reading data into the array from the file
        fin.read(bytes);

        // close the input stream
        fin.close();

        JSONString = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSONString);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (JSONException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return jsonObject;
}

}
```

It keeps showing that error when calling ChooseLevelActivity.class

ChooseLevelActivity.java

```
public class ChooseLevelActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageView level001, level002, level003, level004, level005;
int last_level, best_move;
String best_time, level_selected;
TextView levelName, bestMove, bestTime;
Class <? extends Activity> classVariable;
Button playBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.choose_level);

    level001 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.level001);
    level002 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.level002);
    level003 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.level003);
    level004 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.level004);
    level005 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.level005);

    levelName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.level_name);
    bestMove = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.best_move);
    bestTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.best_time);
    playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);

    // Get the JSON Object from the data
    JSONObject parent = parseJSONData("levels.json");

    // Array of ImageView
    final ImageView[] levelsArray = {level001, level002, level003, level004, level005};

    // This will store all the values inside "best_move and time" in an element string
    try {
        last_level = parent.getInt("level");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < last_level; i++) {
        levelsArray[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        levelsArray[i].setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.level001:
            level_selected = "level001";
            classVariable = Level001Activity.class;
            break;
        case R.id.level002:
            level_selected = "level002";
            classVariable = Level002Activity.class;
            break;
        case R.id.level003:
            level_selected = "level003";
            classVariable = Level003Activity.class;
            break;
        case R.id.level004:
            level_selected = "level004";
            classVariable = Level004Activity.class;
            break;
        case R.id.level005:
            level_selected = "level005";
            classVariable = Level005Activity.class;
            break;
    }

    String fileName = "record_" + level_selected + ".json";

    // Get the JSON Object from the data
    JSONObject parents = parseJSONData(fileName);

    // This will store all the values inside "best_move and time" in an element string
    try {
        best_move = parents.getInt("best_move");
        best_time = parents.getString("best_time");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
       // e.printStackTrace();
    }

    levelName.setText("Level " + level_selected.substring(5));
    bestMove.setText("Best Move: " + best_move);
    bestTime.setText("Best Time: " + best_time);

    playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    classVariable);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

public JSONObject parseJSONData(String file) {
    String JSONString = null;
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        // Open the inputStream to the file
        FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(file);

        int sizeOfJSONFile = fin.available();

        // array that will store all the data
        byte[] bytes = new byte[sizeOfJSONFile];

        // reading data into the array from the file
        fin.read(bytes);

        // close the input stream
        fin.close();

        JSONString = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSONString);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (JSONException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
}
```

Error Stacks:

```
Process: com.example.ed.pieces, PID: 12939
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ed.pieces/com.example.ed.pieces.Level001Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #289: Binary XML file line #289: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #289: Binary XML file line #289: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
        at com.example.ed.pieces.Level001Activity.onCreate(Level001Activity.java:62)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #289: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
        at com.example.ed.pieces.Level001Activity.onCreate(Level001Activity.java:62)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)


 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 10240012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 7MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3948)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:145)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:136)
```

Comment: no good idear to post the same question twice.

Comment: what ? I haven't post the same question twice

Comment: @Charas Compress the high resolution image using bitmap before setting to imageview.

Comment: It is most likely not due to the size of the asset. Please post the code that is generating the exception\

Comment: failed to allocate 10240012 byte` - 10meg file, with 4meg free. why shouldn't it bomb out?

Comment: @Aditya I am setting the image using android:src in my xml layout, how do I compress the image using the bitmap ?

Comment: @Aditya **NO**. Compressing the images won't help. The images will be decompressed in memory anyway.

Comment: What is the maximum image size to be used in an android app ?? is 100KB considered too big ?

Comment: @Charas Please paste your Level001Activity.java,there is android.view.InflateException throwing in your logcat.

Comment: @Aditya the problem lies within the background image of the MainActivity which is 100KB in size. As soon as I remove that background, everything works normally again, no OOM error

Answer (score 1):

**Out of Memory Error**

Out of memory error is very common error when you are developing for a application that deals with multiple images sets or large bitmaps or some Animation stuff. In this case we have to be very careful and efficient while handling the images or object allocation and deallocation. OOM error comes when the allocation crosses the heap limit or your process demand a amount of memory that crosses the heap limit.

In Android, every application runs in a Linux Process. Each Linux Process has a Virtual Machine (Dalvik Virtual Machine) running inside it. There is a limit on the memory a process can demand and it is different for different devices and also differs for phones and tablets. When some process demands a higher memory than its limit it causes a error i.e Out of memory error.

Try this may help you add this tag in your manifest file.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

it will allocate large heap for your app

To convert Drawable into Bitmap,Use this,

```
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo);
Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
```

Using this method,you can decode your image

```
public static Bitmap decodeImageFile(File f,int WIDTH,int HIGHT){
             try {
                 //Decode image size
                 BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                 BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

                 //The new size we want to scale to
                 final int REQUIRED_WIDTH=WIDTH;
                 final int REQUIRED_HIGHT=HIGHT;
                 //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                 int scale=1;
                 while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_WIDTH && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_HIGHT)
                     scale*=2;

                 //Decode with inSampleSize
                 BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 o2.inSampleSize=scale;
                 return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
             } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
             return null;
            }
```

Then call this method where you using this:

```
Bitmap b = decodeImageFile(f, 1280, 720);
```

Comment: Thank you! let me try to implement your answer, I think I found the image that is causing the problem, however the size of the image is only 100KB, is it considered too big in android ?

Answer (score 0):

if your image resolution is high, i suggested you loading image with buffer.

```
String defCoverPath = "drawable/" + "def_cover" + ".png";
yourView.setBackgroundDrawable(LoadResourceImage(defCoverPath));


public static BitmapDrawable LoadResourceImage(String resPath){
        AssetManager assets = MyApp.GetContext().getResources().getAssets();
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable();

        try {
            InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream((assets.open(resPath)));
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer);
            bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(MyApp.GetContext().getResources(), bitmap);
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmapDrawable;
    }
```